# How to prevent multiple instances of the Root-Widget in Kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

OK, I try to make my first App in Kivy and I have a Problem with multiple Instances of my Root Widget.

I need to add widgets to my app while running. (to display a spreadsheet)

But because of the multiple instances of the Root Widget, I can't access the widgets with the kivy ids lookup object.

https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html

I made three Buttons to display the problem in the console
Button -1-, -2-, and -3-

Please explain me why there are multiple instances and how I can prevent it, so the code will work.

Thanks for your help!

File --> Match.py

```
    #!python
    from __future__ import print_function
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
    from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    from kivy.app import App
    import gc

    class my_gc():
        def search_g(self):
            for obj in gc.get_objects():
                if isinstance(obj, Root):
                    try:
                        print(obj.ids)
                    except:
                        print('fail')

    #Root Widget
    class Root(BoxLayout):

        sm = ObjectProperty(None)
        sc0 = ObjectProperty(None)
        sc1 = ObjectProperty(None)
        sc2 = ObjectProperty(None)
        sc3 = ObjectProperty(None)

        mylbl0 = StringProperty('screen 0')
        mylbl1 = StringProperty('screen 1')
        mylbl2 = StringProperty('screen 2')
        mylbl3 = StringProperty('screen 3')

        def find_ids(self):
            print(self.ids)

    class Screen_Manager(ScreenManager):
        pass

    class Screen_0(Screen):
        pass

    class Screen_1(Screen):
        pass

    class Screen_2(Screen):
        pass

    class Screen_3(Screen):
        pass

    class Match(App):
        rootwidget = Root()
        sm = Screen_Manager()
        gc = my_gc()

        def build(self):
            pass

    Match().run()
```

File --> Match.kv

```
    #Root Widget (BoxLayout)
    Root:
        sm: sm
        sc1: sc0
        sc1: sc1
        sc1: sc2
        sc1: sc3
        BoxLayout:
            spacing: '20dp'
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Screen_Manager:
                id: sm
                Screen_0:
                    id: sc0
                    name: 'sc0'
                    manager: 'sm'
                    BoxLayout:
                        id: box_0-0
                        Label:
                            id: lbl_0
                            text: app.rootwidget.mylbl0
                        Label:
                            id: lbl_0-1
                            text: root.mylbl0
                Screen_1:
                    id: sc1
                    name: 'sc1'
                    manager: 'sm'
                    Label:
                        id: lbl1
                        text: root.mylbl1
                Screen_2:
                    id: sc2
                    name: 'sc2'
                    manager: 'sm'
                    Label:
                        id: lbl2
                        text: root.mylbl2
                Screen_3:
                    id: sc3
                    name: 'sc3'
                    manager: 'sm'
                    Label:
                        id: lbl3
                        text: root.mylbl3

            #Tab-Buttons
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: 1 , None
                height: '60dp'
                orientation: 'horizontal'
                Button:
                    text: '-0-'
                    on_press: root.sm.current = sc0.name
                Button:
                    text: '-1-'
                    on_press: root.sm.current = sc1.name
                Button:
                    text: '-2-'
                    on_press: root.sm.current = sc2.name
                Button:
                    text: '-3-'
                    on_press: root.sm.current = sc3.name
                Button:
                    text: '<'
                    size_hint: None , 1
                    width: '60dp'
                    on_press: root.sm.current = root.sm.previous()
                Button:
                    text: '>'
                    size_hint: None , 1
                    width: '60dp'
                    on_press: root.sm.current = root.sm.next()
                Button:
                    text: '-b1-'
                    size_hint: None , 1
                    width: '60dp'
                    #on_press: root.search_g()              #<-- doesn't work
                    on_press: app.gc.search_g()             #<-- works
                Button:
                    text: '-b2-'
                    size_hint: None , 1
                    width: '60dp'
                    on_press: root.find_ids()               #<-- doesn't work
                    on_press: app.rootwidget.find_ids()     #<-- works
                Button:
                    text: '-b3-'
                    size_hint: None , 1
                    width: '60dp'
                    on_press: print(root.mylbl1)            #<-- works
                    on_press: print(app.rootwidget.mylbl1)  #<-- works
```

Comment: actually the buttons to display the problem are -b1-, -b2-, -b3-

Answer (score 0):

## Mutilple Instance - Root Widget

As per your code, you don't have mutiple instances of the root widget. Your root widget is ***Root:*** as per the kv file, *match.kv*.

## root.search_g()

It doesn't work because your root which is the class Root(BoxLayout) does not have the ***search_g()*** method.

## root.find_ids - works

When I commented off *app.rootwidget.find_ids*, the call to *root.find_ids* works i.e. it printed the ids. The keyword ***root*** is available only in rule definitions and represents the root widget of the rule (the first instance of the rule). When your kv file is parsed, kivy collects all the widgets tagged with id’s and places them in *self.ids* dictionary type property.

## app.rootwidget.find_ids

It works but there were no ids because it is referencing to the method find_ids in the initiated object, class Root. The ***rootwidget*** is just a variable by name and it is a different object than the one from ***Root:***

From the attached screen shot, you will notice that the object locations for root.find_ids and app.rootwidget.find_ids are different.

## Adding Widgets Dynamically

To add widgets dynamically into your app while it is running, you have to do the following. For an example, please refer to my other post at [Kivy/python : when i click row then it shows error IndexError: list index out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47158882/kivy-python-when-i-click-row-then-it-shows-error-indexerror-list-index-out-of/47163787?noredirect=1#comment81295964_47163787)

### Python Script - match.py

1. Add an import statement as follow:

   from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
2. Declare a variable (e.g. container) or ObjectProperty type e.g. in the class Root

   class Root(BoxLayout):
       container = ObjectProperty(None)
3. Remove all widgets added dynamically before adding
4. Add widgets dynamically.

### kv File - match.kv

1. Define a layout e.g. BoxLayout or GridLayout in your kv file.
2. Give an id to the layout e.g. container in your kv file.
3. Hook up the ObjectProperty to the id

   Root:
       container: container
   ...
       # Container for adding widgets dynamically
       BoxLayout:
           id: container

## Solution

The solution is to declare an ObjectProperty, rootwidget as follow:

### snippet

```
class Match(App):
    rootwidget = ObjectProperty(None)
    title = "Solution App"

    gc = my_gc()

    def build(self):
        self.rootwidget = Root()
        return self.rootwidget
```

### match.py

```
#!python
from __future__ import print_function
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import App
import gc


class my_gc():
    def search_g(self):
        print("my_gc.search_g called")
        for obj in gc.get_objects():
            if isinstance(obj, Root):
                try:
                    print("obj={0}, ids={1}".format(obj, obj.ids))
                    for key, value in obj.ids.items():
                        print("   key={0}, value={1}".format(key, value))
                except:
                    print('fail')


# Root Widget
class Root(BoxLayout):
    sm = ObjectProperty(None)
    sc0 = ObjectProperty(None)
    sc1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    sc2 = ObjectProperty(None)
    sc3 = ObjectProperty(None)

    mylbl0 = StringProperty('screen 0')
    mylbl1 = StringProperty('screen 1')
    mylbl2 = StringProperty('screen 2')
    mylbl3 = StringProperty('screen 3')

    def find_ids(self):
        print("Root.find_ids called")
        print("self={0}, self.ids={1}".format(self, self.ids))
        for key, value in self.ids.items():
            print("   key={0}, value={1}".format(key, value))


class Screen_Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Screen_0(Screen):
    pass


class Screen_1(Screen):
    pass


class Screen_2(Screen):
    pass


class Screen_3(Screen):
    pass


class Match(App):
    rootwidget = ObjectProperty(None)
    title = "Solution App"

    gc = my_gc()

    def build(self):
        self.rootwidget = Root()
        return self.rootwidget


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Match().run()
```

### match.kv

```
#Root Widget (BoxLayout)
<Root>:
    sm: sm
    sc1: sc0
    sc1: sc1
    sc1: sc2
    sc1: sc3

    BoxLayout:
        spacing: '20dp'
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Screen_Manager:
            id: sm
            Screen_0:
                id: sc0
                name: 'sc0'
                manager: 'sm'
                BoxLayout:
                    id: box_0-0
                    Label:
                        id: lbl_0
                        text: root.mylbl0
                    Label:
                        id: lbl_0-1
                        text: root.mylbl0
            Screen_1:
                id: sc1
                name: 'sc1'
                manager: 'sm'
                Label:
                    id: lbl1
                    text: root.mylbl1
            Screen_2:
                id: sc2
                name: 'sc2'
                manager: 'sm'
                Label:
                    id: lbl2
                    text: root.mylbl2
            Screen_3:
                id: sc3
                name: 'sc3'
                manager: 'sm'
                Label:
                    id: lbl3
                    text: root.mylbl3

        #Tab-Buttons
        BoxLayout:
            id: secondBoxLayout
            size_hint: 1 , None
            height: '60dp'
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            Button:
                text: '-0-'
                on_press: root.sm.current = sc0.name
            Button:
                text: '-1-'
                on_press: root.sm.current = sc1.name
            Button:
                text: '-2-'
                on_press: root.sm.current = sc2.name
            Button:
                text: '-3-'
                on_press: root.sm.current = sc3.name
            Button:
                text: '<'
                size_hint: None , 1
                width: '60dp'
                on_press: root.sm.current = root.sm.previous()
            Button:
                text: '>'
                size_hint: None , 1
                width: '60dp'
                on_press: root.sm.current = root.sm.next()
            Button:
                text: '-b1-'
                size_hint: None , 1
                width: '60dp'
                on_press:
                    print("\non_press: {}".format(self.text))
                    # root.search_g()              #<-- doesn't work
                    print("    app.gc_search_g()")
                    app.gc.search_g()             #<-- works
            Button:
                text: '-b2-'
                size_hint: None , 1
                width: '60dp'
                on_press:
                    print("\non_press: {}".format(self.text))
                    print("    root.find_ids()")
                    root.find_ids()               #<-- works
                    print("\n    app.root.find_ids()")
                    app.rootwidget.find_ids()     #<-- works
            Button:
                text: '-b3-'
                size_hint: None , 1
                width: '60dp'
                on_press:
                    print("\non_press: {}".format(self.text))
                    print(root.mylbl1)            #<-- works
                    print(app.rootwidget.mylbl1)  #<-- works
```

## Output

[image: Figure 1 - Original]
[image: Figure 2 - Solution]

Comment: I have updated my post with steps and example of adding widgets dynamically while app is running.